# Read std::map<string, string> using ReadProcessMemory

Tags: c++, memory, win32-process

My intention is to read value of variable of another process(target) from a process(spy).

I started off with a std::map of size 2 in the target process.

In the spy process, followed the below steps:

- Set UAC Execution Level to "requireAdministrator (/level='requireAdministrator')"
- Enabled SE_DEBUG_NAME
- Opened the target Process
- Used ReadProcessMemory

And successfully read the map. I verified that the size of the read map is  2. But, couldn't evaluate the contents of the map. Each string key/value pair is observed to evaluate to error in the watch window.

To confirm if my steps are correct, I tried out reading an integer variable instead of a map. The value of the integer could be retrieved successfully.

Any advice that helps retrieve the complete contents of the map?

Comment: There might be a mismatch of your's map implementation and the target binary - talking more exactly, if you're compiling your application in msvc 10, and the target application has been build using msvc 11, most likely you will not be able to read it directly.

Comment: Or any other implementation, for that matter.  There are several STL implementations floating around (RogueWave, STLPort, Dinkumware, etc).  What you are attempting to do would only work if you know the EXACT implementation that the target process is actually using, and you know the EXACT layout of the nodes for that particular implementation's `std::map` class.  And, you also have to take 32-bit vs 64-bit differences into account as well.  So what you are asking is not feasible/possible unless you are in control of both target and spy executables (or you have reverse engineered the target).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Thanks, yes, I am exactly doing that, at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The map object contains pointers to nodes, in addition to a node count. You need to use `ReadProcessMemory` on those pointers as well. And if you read the node contents to different addresses in your process address space, you'll need to update the node pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If you own both applications, can you use shared memory (CreateFileMapping/OpenFileMapping and MapViewOfFile) to do this in an easier way?  You could then guard it with a session-specific mutex, serialize the map, write it into the shared memory, then signal a session-specific event when it changes.